# Two-way Data binding is not working using index with ngModel

Tags: angular

I am displaying countries using ngFor along with input boxes. I used input boxes for giving cost to particular product and country. My question is how to display entered value using ngModel, Here i bind [index] with ngModel.

Suppose if i entered 100 for country India, it saves into database fine. But two way dataBinding is not working.

[How to use two way databinding with ngModel using index in angular5 stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yowaud?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Can anyone please help.

Comment: Hi if you want two way data binding just replace `[(ngModel)]="x[i]"` by `[(ngModel)]="x.name"`  its work fine

Comment: Please provide your code.

Comment: just change these line bro which is i mentioned in my previous comment

Comment: I changed that, but not working bro.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to bind to `(keyup)` if you're using `[(ngModel)]`

Just doing this would do:

```
<div class="admin-page">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="co col-md-12">
          <li *ngFor="let x of countries;let i=index">
            <div class="form-group" (click)="country(x)">
              <label>{{x.name}}</label>
            </div>
            <input 
              type="text" 
              class="form-control" 
              [name]="'name_'+i" 
              [(ngModel)]="countries[i].value">  <!-- or [(ngModel)]="x.value" for that matter-->
          </li>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <pre>
    {{ countries | json }}
  </pre>
</div>
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/two-way-data-binding-with-ngmodel?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are showing json data in below, but what i need is if i enter 100 in india that value you are showing in below json but  i need to display in input field.

Comment: Here ngModel need to act as two way data binding.